# Help with functions

Tags: functions

How many functions  $f\ne0$, $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}$

Periodic in an integer $a$ are there so that

$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$$

What I have sofar is that
$$f(a)=f(2a)=f(a)f(a)$$
So that $f(a)=1$,

Also if I multiply $f(x)$ together with itself $a$ times I get that $$f(x)^a=f(x)f(x)f(x)....f(x)=f(ax)=1$$

So that $f(x)^a=1$

I would appreciate any help

Comment: what are the domain and the codomain of this function?

Comment: It seems like the domain is $\mathbb Z$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your argument, we can conclude that $f(1)$ is an $a$th root of unity. Once you know $f(1)$, then $f(n)$ is determined for positive $n\in \mathbb{N}$, as $f(n)=f(1)^n$.

We can also figure out $f(0)=1$ as $1=f(a)=f(0+a)=f(0)\cdot f(a)=f(0)$. That means that $1=f(0)=f(1+(-1))=f(1)f(-1)$, so we also know $f(-1)=\frac{1}{f(1)}$ and from there we know $f(-n)=f(1)^{-n}$ for positive $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Therefore the function $f$ is determined by a choice of an $a$th root of unity for $f(1)$. Conversely, for any $a$th root of unity $\omega$, $n\mapsto \omega^n$ satisfies the requirement for $f$. However, to guarantee the period is exactly $a$ and no less, we must choose an $a$th root of unity $\omega$ with order $a$. There are $\phi(a)$ such choices.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\omega=e^{2\pi i/a}$. You have $f(0)=1$, and $f(1)=\omega^k$ for some integer $k$. This completely determines $f$: $f(n)=\omega^{nk}$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$. However, $f$ has period $a$ iff $k$ is relatively prime to $a$, so there are $\varphi(a)$ such functions, where $\varphi$ is the [Euler totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Comment: Could you elaborate more, I still don't understand how I know for sure that you have constructed all such functions

Comment: @Ethan: It’s immediate from the fact that the value of $f(1)$ completely determines the function, and the fact that the only possible values of $f(1)$ are the $a$-th roots of $1$ with period $a$.

Answer (score 2):

From the equality 
$$f(a)=\left(f(a)\right)^2$$
we have $f(a)=0$ or $f(a)=1$.

If $f(a)=0$ and if we suppose $f(1)=w$ then $w^a=0$ and then $w=0$ so $f(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ is a solution.

If $f(a)=1$ then $w^a=1$ and then $w$ is a root of the unity so $w=e^{2ik\pi/a}$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$ and since $f$ is $a$-periodic so $k$ is  relatively prime to $a$ hence there are $\varphi(a)+1$ solutions

Comment: Sorry it seems during one of my edits I removed the part about $f\ne 0$